# Writing advice for a junior PhD student writing a single-author paper

Tags: journals, writing, authorship, writing-style

I am a second year theoretical physics PhD student authoring a paper on my own in a subfield completely different from my advisor's (in my free time, with his blessing).

My question is specifically about *writing* advice. In all my previous papers, I have always had experienced senior co-authors looking over my writing, telling me what's appropriate and what isn't, how to handle specific things, how to best present results to appease reviewers and editors and, of course, significantly polishing my manuscripts. Now I have completely lost this advantage, and while I have improved a lot, I am afraid it is not enough.

How do I make up for the lack of experienced collaborators with my writing? Are there specific writing tips that can help with single author papers? What are some common mistakes junior PhD students make while writing, that my coauthors might catch (if they existed)?

Comment: I suspect your advisor is your best guide even if the fields are different. They have much more experience in writing/expression/ etc than you do. It might be better to get advice along the way rather than in one big lump, but that might depend on the advisor's preference.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you, I'll try to ask him for advice when he has the time, but he's somewhat hands off and he didn't seem very interested in getting involved with my independent endeavors (although he encourages them to "keep me sharp").

Comment: 40 pages is extremely long for a physics paper.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It is quite long indeed, but it is for a computational physics journal that requires a lot of examples of usage and an explanation of the theory. It also has a large number of figures that I assume will be compressed to a smaller size by the journal if accepted. It is very similar to this preprint's size, and I plan to submit the same (very new) journal. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14822.pdf

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It also seems to be the norm in fields like Quantum Gravity, which I have a few friends working in, see e.g. this recent work https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.16289.pdf

Comment: 40 (single-column) pages is not extremely long in all physics subfields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In all my previous papers, I have always had experienced senior authors looking over my writing, telling me what's appropriate and what isn't, how to handle specific things, how to best present results to appease reviewers and editors and, of course, significantly polishing my manuscripts

You want to continue to have all of these things, just perhaps *under your own power* and *at a more complete stage of development* (not necessarily when you are almost finished, but when you know clearly what you want to ask). You've hopefully collected some of the advice you've gotten in the past on your work not just as specific advice on that paper but as direction on your writing in general.

However, you still want to have senior advisors look over your writing. Writing a single-author paper doesn't separate you from the need for that guidance. Even tenured professors share their writing with peers (and students) for feedback.

If you are unsure if an approach is appropriate/how to handle something specific, ask an advisor. It's your work, so don't ask "what should I do?", ask "do you think X or Y would be better?" (it's okay if the answer is Z), but don't be afraid to get advice. There is a lot of feedback you can get without sharing all of your writing - you can get advice without someone needing to read 40 pages to give it.

The polishing stage is probably something you need to take more control of, but once you've polished it as best you can, once you've let it sit for a few days before coming back to editing it with a fresh view yourself a couple times, you'll still likely need someone else's feedback. Few people can write well without it.

If possible, you may be able to split some of the burden to more than one person. Your peers can help as well - and you can trade your own efforts on their projects - and hopefully this can limit the advice your advisor needs to give.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent advice! I've gotten in touch with one of my senior collaborators and he said he'd be happy to give me some advice once I have a more polished manuscript. I will continue to work on it and see if any other graduate students would like to help. I appreciate it!